# Error message after Windows start-up

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Every time I start up my I get this Error message. How do I fix it ? I cant understand anything from this error message.

[image]

When I click cancel Microsoft C++ studio opens up.

EDIT: I am able to boot up and do everything normal but I just get this one error message after logging in to Windows XP. Then I click on OK to terminate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your post whether you can still boot into Windows and manipulate files.
(Clicking Cancel means debugging Explorer, using whatever debugger you have installed.)

The possibilities are:

1. A bad plugin installed in Explorer
2. Virus infection that failed to take over Explorer
3. Windows files are damaged

The possible solutions are in order: (1) find and uninstall plugin, (2) antivirus scans, (3) system repair, (4) total reinstall.

First, boot in Safe mode and see if this problem still arrives. If it doesn't happen any more, locate and uninstall the Explorer plugin. If none, locate and uninstall the product that causes the problem.

Use some antiviruses to deeply scan the hard disk. If you can't boot even in Safe mode, use a rescue live-CD virus scanner : I like best [Avira AntiVir Rescue System](http://www.free-av.com/en/tools/12/avira%5Fantivir%5Frescue%5Fsystem.html) because it gets updated several times a day and so the download CD is up-to-date.

If no virus is found, use [sfc /scannow](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ht/sfc-scannow.htm) to repair important Windows files.

If that also doesn't work, you should [Perform a Repair Installation](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

If nothing works, you should format the hard disk and reinstall Windows. Save first all data, of course.

Comment: OK I played around with windows for a while and found that When I disable Flash-note from start-up, I no longer get the message. Is there any-workaround without disabling it from start-up

Comment: I don't know Flashnote. If you don't use it, uninstall using Revo Uninstaller Freeware. If you do need it, then (1) maybe find another such product, or (2) contact the developers and have them fix it.